# Remotely generating key pair without passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to generate the key pair (without a passphrase) on a remote machine.
The command I use for this is:

```
ssh root@REMOTEIP ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa_new -q -N ""
```

The output of this command is:

```
ssh-keygen: option requires an argument -- N
Usage: ssh-keygen [options]
Options:
  -a trials   Number of trials for screening DH-GEX moduli.
  -B          Show bubblebabble digest of key file.
  -b bits     Number of bits in the key to create.
  -C comment  Provide new comment.
  -c          Change comment in private and public key files.
  -e          Convert OpenSSH to IETF SECSH key file.
  -F hostname Find hostname in known hosts file.
  -f filename Filename of the key file.
  -G file     Generate candidates for DH-GEX moduli.
  -g          Use generic DNS resource record format.
  -H          Hash names in known_hosts file.
  -i          Convert IETF SECSH to OpenSSH key file.
  -l          Show fingerprint of key file.
  -M memory   Amount of memory (MB) to use for generating DH-GEX moduli.
  -N phrase   Provide new passphrase.
  -P phrase   Provide old passphrase.
  -p          Change passphrase of private key file.
  -q          Quiet.
  -R hostname Remove host from known_hosts file.
  -r hostname Print DNS resource record.
  -S start    Start point (hex) for generating DH-GEX moduli.
  -T file     Screen candidates for DH-GEX moduli.
  -t type     Specify type of key to create.
  -v          Verbose.
  -W gen      Generator to use for generating DH-GEX moduli.
  -y          Read private key file and print public key.
```

When I use a passphrase, the command works just fine:

```
ssh root@REMOTEIP ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa_new -q -N "12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, you have to quote the entire command to avoid it being split by your local shell:

```
ssh root@REMOTEIP "ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa_new -q -N ''"
```

---

The problem is that `ssh`, aiming to be compatible with `rsh` (which it initially replaced), sends the entire command line as a *single* argument that is later passed to the remote shell (on Unix, `$SHELL -c "your command"`).

1. When you run

   `ssh root@REMOTEIP ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa_new -q -N ""`
2. the local shell executes

   `["ssh", "root@REMOTEIP", "ssh-keygen", "-t", "rsa", "-f", "/root/.ssh/id_rsa_new", "-q", "-N", ""]`
3. which `ssh` concatenates together to get

   `"ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa_new -q -N "`
4. and the remote shell splits again to

   `["ssh-keygen", "-t", "rsa", "-f", "/root/.ssh/id_rsa_new", "-q", "-N"]`

   – notice the missing empty arguments.